# Bootstrap - One row with two columns and position all other columns under second column of first row,

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for the really confusing title. What I'm trying to do should be quite easy in theory.

I think the best way to demontrate it is by showing you an image:

[image]

1 row at the top with 2 columns, and every other column coming after that should be positioned under the second column...

Is this doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the "offset" classes are for. `col-md-offset-1` applied to the elements in the second column (as *additional* class) should do what you want (for medium viewport size)

(probably you use wider columns with classes like `col-md-3` that span three columns of the grid. In this case you'd need `col-md-offset-3`for the offset)

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that the column has a size of `col-md-3` and if I add another column to that, I get another column in the row...

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried `col-md-offset-3` and I simply get 2 columns per row.

Comment: @Katie how about pasting your html here?

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML `display : flex` for such layout. For example refer below link.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox
Try below code snippet.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"><div class="well">1</div></div>
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">2</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">3</div></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">4</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use col-md-offset-* class

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-6" style="text-align=center;"><p>fixed column</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-6" style="text-align=center;"><p>col</p></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-6" style="text-align=center;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-6" style="text-align=center;"><p>col</p></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-6" style="text-align=center;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-6" style="text-align=center;"><p>col</p></div>
</div>
```

for more information :

[Bootstrap Grid System](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) - [Bootstrap Grid Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp) -